# Angular/RxJs 6 - combining route params and query params not working anymore

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I've spent at least 2 hours trying to get things work with version 6 but no avail. I just cannot get both route params and queryparams.

This is the closest syntax to the older versions but it only logs query params.

What I want to do is wrap this in global routing service so the method call is clean and if any other updates occur I can change in one place.

```
    import {BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, Observable} from 'rxjs';

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute)
// body of constructor left out


     // Combine them both into a single observable
    const urlParams: Observable<any> = combineLatest(
        this.route.params,
        this.route.queryParams,
        (params, queryParams) => ({ ...params, ...queryParams})
    );

    urlParams.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I also noticed that combinedLatest isn't in 'rxjs/operators' for some reason.
Observable.combineLatest doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With rxjs6 there is no more result selector so you need to use 'map' instead. Documentation on migration [rxjs migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

```
import {BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'

    const urlParams: Observable<any> =  combineLatest(
        this.route.params,
        this.route.queryParams
      ).pipe(
          map(([params, queryParams]) => ({...params, ...queryParams}))
      );

    urlParams.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: I realized that this works in my ngOnit component but not in my singleton service. That is, the route param only shows up when using inside the component. The singleton service does show the queryparam though. I wonder if injecting the service into the component instead of being global would fix it.

Comment: i would recommend using it in component cause there can be a lot of bugs when using in service, cause sometimes it doesn;t know activatedRoute.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working by keeping the service local and returning the observable although it's emitting both the current and the new route. I just want to avoid calling the router directly in all my components because the Angular team is always changing those apis. The more stuff I can wrap, the better.

Comment: @Smith i understand You :-)

Comment: This shows that combineLatest has been deprecated

Answer (score 1):

combineLatest provides one output in array format...
Please try using as follows

```
t$ = combineLatest(
  this.route.params,
  this.route.queryParams
).pipe(
  map(results => ({params: results[0], queryParams: results[1]}))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this and console.log, params is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem and the accepted answer kind of works but if you change route params and query params at the same time, the subscription will be triggered twice.
To avoid that, I used `distinctUntilChanged`:

```
combineLatest(
      this.route.params.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)),
      this.route.queryParams.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    )
      .pipe(map(([params, queryParams]) => ({params, queryParams})))
      .subscribe(({params, queryParams}) => {
         console.log(params, queryParams);
      });
```

Comment: Don't you need a custom comparer to make your distinctUntilChanged more accurate?